# Is it possible whole Partition with same structure in Linux

Tags: rhel, data-recovery

Well one of my colleague installed fresh OS Redhat 6 on already in use test server. Now we got in trouble and needed to recover whole partition which is already formatted during new installation.

Is it possible to recover whole partition with same structure as it was before installing new OS

Comment: You're asking about recovery, but you haven't mentioned what filesystem was used.

Comment: Filesysem was ext3 Redhat 5.9

Answer (score 0):

Recovering data from formatted drive or from a deleted partition is a bit of possible thing. But recovering data from drive which was formatted and then written upon is not possible, since data might be overwritten and accessing the old data is impossible now.

Though you could try your luck with `testdisk` utility. But sorry, as far as my knowledge it won't help.